# How to draw the following Feynman diagrams?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-feynman

I tried to draw the diagrams below using Tikzs in Latex.
However, I failed to do it. I looked into the documentation but didn't figure it out.

[image: Diagram1]

[image: Diagram]

Any help will be highly appreciated.

For the first diagram, I tried the following, but it is not exactly what I want

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={a=1.2;b=1.5;}]
    \draw[teal,dashed,rotate=-22.5] (90:a) 
        foreach \X in {45,0,...,-180}  
            {-- (\X:a) edge ++ (\X:0.5)} -- (135:a); 
             
    \draw node[circle,fill,draw,inner sep=0.8ex](O){}
         foreach \X [count=\Y] in {45,0,...,-225}
            {(\X:b) node[circle,draw,thin,inner sep=0.5ex](p\Y){} edge[very thick] (O)}; 

    \path foreach \X [count=\Y from 2] in {n-1,n,1,2,3}   {(p\Y)  (O)}; 
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think it could help if you show your attempt. Also, what part is it that you have problems with? To me this looks like a bunch of lines and dots, essentially.

Comment: @mickep, thanks for your comment. I added what I tried for the first diagram.

Comment: There are packages/libraries that aid in creating Feynman diagrams somewhat. (You even tagged one.) They don't offer a solution to draw the dashed lines, though. Your first attempt doesn't look bad.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Thanks for your suggestions. I didn't try Tikz-Feynman because it cannot draw the dashed lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so I have managed to do it myself; here is the code for hexagon

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={a=1.2;b=1.5;}]
 \draw[thick,blue,dash pattern=on 2pt off 2pt,line cap=round] (180:0.8) edge ++ (180:0.4)
 -- (120:0.8) edge ++ (120:0.4)
 -- (60:0.8) edge ++ (60:0.4)
 -- (0:0.8) edge ++ (0:0.4) -- (-60:0.8)  edge ++ (-60:0.4)-- (-120:0.8)  edge ++ (-120:0.4) -- cycle;
 node[anchor=west]{};
\draw[thick] (0,0) node[circle,fill,inner sep=3pt,draw](O) {}
(150:1.1) node[circle,draw,inner sep=1.2pt]{}
 edge (O)
 (90:1.1) node[circle,draw,inner sep=1.2pt]{}
 edge (O)
 (30:1.1) node[circle,draw,inner sep=1.2pt]{}
 edge (O)
 (-30:1.1) node[circle,draw,inner sep=1.2pt]{}
 edge (O)
 (-90:1.1) node[circle,draw,inner sep=1.2pt]{}
 edge (O) 
 (-150:1.1) node[circle,draw,inner sep=1.2pt]{}
 edge (O);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and this is for the double box

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thick,blue,dash pattern=on 2pt off 2pt,line cap=round] (-0.55,0.6) edge ++ (-0.3,0.2)
-- (-0.55,-0.6) edge ++ (-0.3,-0.2)
-- (0.55,-0.6) edge ++ (0,-0.35)
-- (1.6,-0.6) edge ++ (0.3,-0.2)
-- (1.6,0.6) edge ++ (0.3,0.2)
-- (0.55,0.6) edge ++ (0,0.35) -- cycle ;
\draw[thick,blue,dash pattern=on 2pt off 2pt,line cap=round] (0.55,0.6) -- (0.55,-0.6) ;
 \draw[thick] (0,0) node[circle,fill,inner sep=3pt,draw](O) {}
 (1.1,0) node[circle,fill,inner sep=3pt,draw](OO) {}
 (180:1) node[circle,draw,inner sep=1.2pt]{}edge (O)
 (90:1) node[circle,draw,inner sep=1.2pt]{}
 edge (O)
 (270:1) node[circle,draw,inner sep=1.2pt]{}
 edge (O)
 (0:1) node[circle,draw,inner sep=1.2pt]{}
 edge (O)
  (1.1,1.1) node[circle,draw,inner sep=1.2pt]{}
 edge (OO)
 (1.1,-1.1) node[circle,draw,inner sep=1.2pt]{}
 edge (OO)
 (2.1,0) node[circle,draw,inner sep=1.2pt]{}
 edge (OO);
 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: you could define a custom style for the outer circles. In that way you only would have to change the style definition in order to change the look of the circles. Something like that works `\tikzset{outer_circ/.style = {circle,draw,inner sep=1.2pt}}`